# Spring Boot application not connecting with Cloud Config Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

My Spring boot application , which was connecting with a Spring Cloud Config Server to fetch externalized properties, suddenly is not connecting/talking to the config server. I was doing many changes and am not sure which one could have lead to this problem.

1. I verified the bootstrap.yml file in my spring boot application , the following configuration exists and the spring cloud config server is running in that location

   spring:
     application:
       name: abc
     cloud:
       config:
         uri: http://localhost:8888/
2. I can see the config server is running in the 8888 port. Validated it by running the "env" endpoint for this URL
3. I can see the abc.yml , abc.properties files present in the config server

**Question**: How can i trace, where the problem is ?

Answer (score 1):

There was an environment variable "spring.application.name" forcibly set with a value "xyz" by someone with a value different from the application name which i had mentioned in my bootstrap.yml

Since environment variables over-ride the property file values, my spring boot application was looking for xyz.yml or xyz.properties

Once i removed the environment variable, things started working fine.